# Using user-defined types in Cassandra with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, cassandra

I am trying to use user-defined types in Cassandra with nodejs.
Following the documentation, I successfully manage to do it in cqlsh (https://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/cqlUseUDT.html). I manage to insert items in cqlsh but not ussing the `cassandra-driver` module.

I understand they are some intricacies do to the use of javascript (http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/nodejs-driver/1.0/nodejs-driver/reference/nodejs2Cql3Datatypes.html) and I have tried the different options offered but I couldnt not get it to work.

Here are my trials and their resulting error message:

```
var insertQuery = 'INSERT INTO mykeyspace.users (id, name) VALUES (?, ?)'

client.execute(insertQuery, ['62c36092-82a1-3a00-93r1-46196ee77204', { firstname: 'paul', lastname: 'jacques'}], {hints: ['uuid', 'map<text, text>']}, function(err) { console.log(err);})
```

> > `{ name: 'ResponseError',
> >       message: 'Not enough bytes to read 0th field java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=9 cap=9]',
> >       info: 'Represents an error message from the server',
> >       code: 8704,
> >       query: 'INSERT INTO mykeyspace.users (id, name) VALUES (?, ?)' }`

```
client.execute(insertQuery, ['62c36092-82a1-3a00-93r1-46196ee77204', { firstname: 'paul', lastname: 'jacques'}], { prepare: true }, function(err) { console.log(err);})

    { [TypeError: Not a valid blob, expected Buffer obtained { firstname: 'paul', lastname: 'jacques' }]
  query: 'INSERT INTO mykeyspace.users (id, name) VALUES (?, ?)' }
```

Then what is the correct syntax to get it to work?

NB. I am using cassandra 2.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DataStax Node.js driver does not support User defined types yet, so the driver won't be able to serialize the data accordingly.

You can use json notation in CQL to access the individual fields. For example, queries like the following will work:

```
SELECT addr.street, addr.city FROM location WHERE id=?;
```

or

```
UPDATE SET addr['street'] = ?, addr['city'] = ? WHERE id = ?
```

Comment: Thanks, what is the preferred way to store nested json objects then? I am currently using blobs but this makes querying over bufferised column impossible and updates more expensive...

Comment: Frozen UDTs are for small objects, if you can get it working with the json notation I included in my answer, you should use it (later you can use driver level udt).
If you need large objects, you can use multiple columns or you should use a different column family for it.